# Searching between 2 different time periods

Tags: datetime, parameters, hour

I would like to be able to have a stored procedure that will allow the user to search between 2 different time frames based off of a parameter that will say whether they are searching for results on a full 24 hour period or based off the business hours. Would a case statement in the where clause be the best choice? This will be a stored procedure that will be used in an SSRS report and the user will choose between "Calendar Day" and "Business Day" in a drop-down menu to specify the type of day defined by the parameter in the stored procedure. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd need to use a CASE statement in your WHERE clause. You could probably just get away with ANDs and ORs.

```
WHERE 
    (Parameter = 'Calendar Day')
    or
    (Parameter = 'Business Day' and DATEPART(HOUR, DateField) between 9 and 17)
```

The where clause won't compare the hour when its a calendar day but when it's a business day, the time needs to be between 9 am and 5 pm.